# Strange line in CSS Transform Scale Hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get raid of this strange line from many days but can't figure out why this line is still showing up upon hover. (`z-index`on parent and image div but nope still the same)

Basically it appear when **image shift 1px to the left** and it show red background as line. **It will be white if you set background to transparent.**

Replicate: https://jsfiddle.net/o67hx6u7/

*hover on second column and you will see a red line.

**GIF:** In case you can't see line:

[image]

Comment: Can not see the red line if I get rid of this, background: rgb(255, 0, 0); from .ss-row-slid on your fiddle.

Comment: @Dcoto Then it will take white (body) background and show white line. Please see my updated question with GIF demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Still can't see it to be honest you could try background-color: transparent or is that still white?

Comment: @Dcoto it's red on purpose so you can see it clearly. It will be white if you make it transparent. it will be blue if you set bg to blue. The issue is why it shift image to left.

Comment: Open this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY35L.gif (it's a gif)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
.ss-row-slid {
    min-height: 600px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

with

```
.ss-row-slid {
    min-height: 600px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: Btw it was red on a purpose so people can see line clearly.

Comment: @YOU should probably add that to your initial post to stop confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find the real cause for the problem but unfortunately i could not find the real solution.

But there is one interesting thing, Red line is only visible at certain values of `window.innerWidth` for example `841, 873, 913, 921, 1073 ...` and for rest it works perfect.

The culprit in your situation is `transform: scale(1.1)` property.

The fix that i found is set

```
.row-slid-inner-bg {
    width: 101%;
}
```

I hope this helps!